# MS Access, create a relationship with a form and subform

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, subform

So, my problem is that i have a form like so:

[image]

this screen is located inside a navigation form and is called "Student Details"

I created a query with the following code and turned said query into a subform:

```
SELECT [student subjects].[student id],[student subjects].[Subject Code], [student subjects].[Class Number], [student subjects].Result
FROM [student subjects]
WHERE [student subjects].[student id] = Forms![Navigation Form].Form![student id];
```

Essentially, what i want to happen is for the subject code, class number and results of a student to appear in the subform below; so i thought i would go about this by stating that the student IDs must be the same.

Some more information, the information at the top of the image is in a different table from the information in the subform.

However, as you can see, the subform only replicates the student ID and not the other fields. I would like to rectify this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. Maybe the columns you selected are empty or not saved yet.

BTW: there are properties for the subform where you can relate to the parent form. I think the english property name is *Link Child Field* and *Link Master Field*
Just put the fieldname of your Ids in there.

**EDIT**

See also here

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b?rs=en-US&ui=en-US&ad=US

Comment: I tried to mess around with the link child and master field commands a bit earlier, but to no avail. I think the problem may have to do with the where statement in my code, perhaps i referred to the text box incorrectly..?

Comment: Good point. Maybe you can try: `Forms![Navigation Form]![student id]`
With the link child and master field: Do a tutorial to understand the mechanics. It will simplify a lot of thing. Or just use the subform wizard

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Also this subform i have already was made with the wizard

Comment: Okay, basically, if the student ID appears it must be a valid query. It is not so easy debugging this from here, so I can only give you a hint: Try your query with the query designer and show it on the query datasheet when the form is open. There you can change the query and designer as often as you want until you have the right query

Comment: When i try running my query NOT in the form but directly from the place where i write the query itself, i get no results returned. I think this suggests that i am in fact writing the wrong query?

Comment: Probably! BTW: If you have linked the subform with the parent form with the wizard as described, you do not need a WHERE Statement in your query for the subform!

Comment: By taking out the where statement, the exact same result is achieved. So i think i have to do this without linking them somehow, but i cant figure it out. I still think it has to do with the where clause but everything i've tried has either shown all results or none of them.

Comment: Maybe there is no data in the fields in the subform. Without the Where statement and with linked fields enabled: Have you tried to input data and watch it again? I am sorry for stating that, but a linked subform is really basic Access, supported by wizard, and I suggest you to watch at least a Youtube Tutorial about that topic

Comment: I've watched numerous tutorials but the issue is that i can't find one on the simple topic of displaying different data depending on what record is currently selected. And while inputting data, i realised that it in fact seemingly is holding NO data. I'm not sure why, since I've linked them to one another...

Comment: I followed that video to the T and I ran into the exact same problem, it displays only the ID... im really confused about this @.@

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92147/discussion-between-asdev-and-bluerhapsody).